# Использование Kanboard в качестве базового инструмента для канбан приложения

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Необходимо создать канбан приложение, в котором будет возможность в  разделении прав, создании контента, возможности создавать чат и многое другое. Подскажите, можно ли использовать Kanboard, как основу для этого или всё же лучше делать такое приложение с нуля? Как сильно Kanboard расширяем и гибок под необходимый функционал?